# Groovy Reusable Functions - Extract Node Value - groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm a Groovy noob and trying to get my head around using reusable functions to extract an xml node value for a given test step and node in SoapUI. It seems the class runs fine but the problem is when using the method. I get the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.log4j.Logger.info() is         applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [return TestStepName, Node] Possible solutions: info(java.lang.Object), info(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Throwable), any(), wait(), dump(), find(groovy.lang.Closure) error at line:
```

This is my class:

```
class Example
{
def log
def context
def responseSOAXmlStep
def resultValue
def responseNodePath
def storeProperty
// Class constructor with same case as Class name
def Example(logIn,contextIn,testRunnerIn)
    {
    this.log = logIn
    this.context = contextIn
    this.responseSOAXmlStep = responseSOAXmlStep
    this.responseNodePath = responseNodePath
    }

    def execute(responseSOAXmlStep,responseNodePath)
{
    def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
        // do some stuff to prove I've run with right context, etc.
        log.info "return "+responseSOAXmlStep,responseNodePath

    def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( responseSOAXmlStep+"#ResponseAsXml" );
    resultValue = holder.getNodeValue( "//ns1:"+responseNodePath );
    log.info("Node value: " +  resultValue );
    testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue(storeProperty, resultValue);


        return execute
}

}
context.setProperty( "example", new Example( log, context, testRunner) )
log.info "Library Context:"+context
```

This is where I do the call in a step after the response step:

```
// get a reference to the library TestSuite
library = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["Library"]

// find the module within the library 
module = library.testCases["Library"].testSteps["Second Example_Class"]

// initialise the library; which places an instance of Example in the context
module.run(testRunner, context)

// get the instance of example from the context.
def example = context.example

// run the method, with parameter
log.info "example.execute(responseSOAXmlStep,responseNodePath) = " +        example.execute("TestStepName","Node")
```

I've searched the forum but could not find an answer that suites my query. Any form of assistance is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error description says that you're invoking `info()` method on `log` passing two `strings` as and arguments, and this method doesn't exist.

The problem is easy to solve, pass one concatenated string with `+` as parameter instead of passing two strings. In your `execute` method inside your `Example` class use this:

```
def execute(responseSOAXmlStep,responseNodePath)
{
...
    // USE + TO CONCATENATE STRINGS INSTEAD OF USE , 
    log.info "return " + responseSOAXmlStep + responseNodePath
...
}
```

instead of:

```
def execute(responseSOAXmlStep,responseNodePath)
{
...
    // do some stuff to prove I've run with right context, etc.
    log.info "return " + responseSOAXmlStep,responseNodePath 
...
}
```

**EDIT:**

As you said in your comment probably you've another problem storing properties in `TestSuite` level. You're using this code:

`testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue(storeProperty, resultValue);`

The problem is that `setPropertyValue` is expecting `string` as a first argument however at this line in your code `storeProperty` is not defined yet. Try for example defining `storeProperty` as:

`def storeProperty = "myProperty"` before using it in `setPropertyValue` call.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you very much albcliff, that worked! I'm now trying to write the extracted XML value into a property name specified by the user which will be stored at Test Suite level.

Comment: You're storing the properties in TestSuite level correctly with: testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue(storeProperty, resultValue);. I think the problem is that setPropertyValue method expects a string as a first argument and you're passing storeProperty object which wasn't initialized. Make a try defining storeProperty as for example: def storeProperty = "myProperty"; in your class Example.

Comment: I've got it to store the node value in a variable supplied by the user. The issue is I get error message: groovy.lang.missingpropertyexception no such property for class:

This is the method with parameters that i'm using:

log.info "GetXmlNode.execute(responseSOAXmlStep,responseNodePath,storeProperty) = " + GetXmlNode.execute("AuthProxyPostSession","sessionId","Id")

I've included the below in the Class:
 def storeProperty = "id"
this.storeProperty = storeProperty
def execute(responseSOAXmlStep,responseNodePath,storeProperty)